Texture Distortion on on Cylindrical Mesh
I’m modeling this shaving cream bottle in Blender using two textures: one for the front and one for the back. However, I’m running into an issue during UV mapping. The texture appears curved around the cylindrical mesh instead of aligning properly in a flat orientation.



okay so, when i do remove the subdivision subsurface modifier, it does get fixed but i dont understand why's this issue occuring.

Maybe in the Subdivision Surface modifier, under Advanced > UV Smooth, try the Keep Corners option? Or please pack the image and share your file

If you're using the subdivision surface modifier, you have to modify the UV Smooth section to Keep Corners (or play around with the other options). This will most likely fix it, since this look exactly like this is the issue.


